# Como implementar la paginacion en React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy realizando la paginacion de 100 tarjetas, como pueden observar en el codigo, quiero presentarlas de 10 en 10 por pagina, la informacion que incluyen estas 100 tarjetas las obtengo de un API de JasonPlaceHolder por medio de `axios.post`, por lo que realizo un map para que obtenga el valor de 100 post diferentes.

Esta es la direccion del API:

> https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

En el codigo puedo visualizar los botones y los numeros de la paginacion, de hecho funcionan los botones ya que el numero de la pagina va cambiando, pero sigo visualizando las 100 tarjetas en una sola pagina y no de 10 en 10 por pagina, el codigo para la paginacion lo tome de la siguiente direccion:

> https://codesandbox.io/s/z2rr7z23ol

El cual es un ejemplo de "react-paginating", pueden encontrar el repositorio de Github en la siguiente direccion:

> https://github.com/ChoTotOSS/react-paginating

El npm lo pueden encontrar en la siguiente direccion:

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paginating

Su instalacion se realiza con el siguiente comando:

```
npm install --save react-paginating
```

En la linea 112 tengo lo siguiente:

```
{articles//[currentPage -1]
```

El calculo del "currentPage - 1", lo tengo comentado porque me marca undefined para el valor del `.sort`, ya que en teoria con este calculo deberian visualizarse 10 tarjetas por pagina, asi tendria un total de 10 paginas.

Imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Usando `react-paginating` puedo lograrlo? o conocen una forma mejor para poder llevar a cabo esta tarea?

A continuacion les presento mi codigo:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Button, Typography} from '@material-ui/core';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardHeader from '@material-ui/core/CardHeader';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import Collapse from '@material-ui/core/Collapse';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import blue from '@material-ui/core/colors/blue';
import FavoriteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Favorite';
import ShareIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Share';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';
import MoreVertIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoreVert';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import moment from 'moment';
import axios from 'axios';
import Pagina from './Pagination';
import Pagination from 'react-paginating';

const articles = [];
const limit = 10;
const pageCount = 3;
const total = articles.length*limit;

const styles = theme => ({
    card: {
      maxWidth: 400,
    },
    media: {
      height: 0,
      paddingTop: '56.25%', // 16:9
    },
    actions: {
      display: 'flex',
    },
    expand: {
      transform: 'rotate(0deg)',
      marginLeft: 'auto',
      transition: theme.transitions.create('transform', {
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.shortest,
      }),
    },
    expandOpen: {
      transform: 'rotate(180deg)',
    },
    avatar: {
      backgroundColor: blue[500],
    },
  });

class Mainview extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {articles:[],
            expanded: false,
            currentPage: 1,
                    };
        this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
        this.handleEdit = this.handleEdit.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        const { onLoad } = this.props;
        axios('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        .then((response) => { console.log(response); onLoad(response.data)});
    }

    handleDelete(id) {
        const { onDelete } =this.props;
        return axios.delete(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`)
        .then(() => onDelete(id));
    }

    handleEdit(data) {
        const { setEdit } = this.props;

        setEdit(data);
    }

    handleExpandClick = () => {
        this.setState(state => ({ expanded: !state.expanded }));
      };

      handlePageChange = (page, e) => {
        this.setState({
          currentPage: page
        });
      }

    render(){
        const { classes, articles, currentPage } = this.props;
        const limit = 2;
        const pageCount = 3;
        const total = articles.length*limit;

        console.log("STATE POSTS",this.state.posts);
        return(
            <div align="center">
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <Typography><h1>Posts</h1></Typography>
                {articles//[currentPage -1]
                .sort(({ id: previousID }, { id: currentID}) => previousID - currentID)   
                .map(data =>
                    <div>
                        <Grid>
                        <Card className={classes.card}>
                        <CardHeader
                            avatar={
                                <Avatar aria-label="Recipe" className={classes.avatar}>
                                EA
                                </Avatar>
                            }
                            action={
                                <IconButton>
                                <MoreVertIcon />
                                </IconButton>
                            }
                        title={data.title}
                        //subheader={data.user !== undefined ? data.user.username : "Erick"}
                        />
                        <CardMedia
                        className={classes.media}
                        image="/static/images/cards/paella.jpg"
                        title="Paella dish"
                        />
                        <CardContent>
                        <Typography component="p">
                        <div>{data.id}.- {data.body}</div>
                        <div><b></b> {moment(new Date(data.createdAt)).fromNow()}</div>
                        </Typography>
                        </CardContent>
                        <CardActions className={classes.actions} disableActionSpacing>
                            <IconButton aria-label="Add to favorites">
                                <FavoriteIcon />
                            </IconButton>
                            <IconButton aria-label="Share">
                                <ShareIcon />
                            </IconButton>
                            <IconButton
                                className={classnames(classes.expand, {
                                [classes.expandOpen]: this.state.expanded,
                                })}
                                onClick={this.handleExpandClick}
                                aria-expanded={this.state.expanded}
                                aria-label="Show more"
                            >
                                <ExpandMoreIcon />
                            </IconButton>
                            <Button onClick={() => this.handleDelete(data._id)}>Eliminar</Button>
                            <Button onClick={() => this.handleEdit(data)}>Editar</Button>
                            <Button>Leer</Button>
                        </CardActions>
                            <Collapse in={this.state.expanded} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                                <CardContent>
                                    <Typography paragraph>
                                    Aqui va mas texto
                                    </Typography>
                                    <Typography paragraph>
                                    Y aqui tambien
                                    </Typography>
                                </CardContent>
                            </Collapse>
                        </Card>
                        </Grid>
                        <br/>
                    </div>
                    )}
                );
                <Pagination
          total={total}
          limit={limit}
          pageCount={pageCount}
          currentPage={currentPage}
        >
          {({
            pages,
            currentPage,
            hasNextPage,
            hasPreviousPage,
            previousPage,
            nextPage,
            totalPages,
            getPageItemProps
          }) => (
            <div>
              <button
                {...getPageItemProps({
                  pageValue: 1,
                  onPageChange: this.handlePageChange
                })}
              >
                first
              </button>

              {hasPreviousPage && (
                <button
                  {...getPageItemProps({
                    pageValue: previousPage,
                    onPageChange: this.handlePageChange
                  })}
                >
                  {"<"}
                </button>
              )}

              {pages.map(page => {
                let activePage = null;
                if (currentPage === page) {
                  activePage = { backgroundColor: "#fdce09" };
                }
                return (
                  <button
                    {...getPageItemProps({
                      pageValue: page,
                      key: page,
                      style: activePage,
                      onPageChange: this.handlePageChange
                    })}
                  >
                    {page}
                  </button>
                );
              })}

              {hasNextPage && (
                <button
                  {...getPageItemProps({
                    pageValue: nextPage,
                    onPageChange: this.handlePageChange
                  })}
                >
                  {">"}
                </button>
              )}

              <button
                {...getPageItemProps({
                  pageValue: totalPages,
                  onPageChange: this.handlePageChange
                })}
              >
                last
              </button>
            </div>
          )}
        </Pagination>
          <Pagina />
                                <br />
                                <br />
                                <br />
                                <br />
                                <br />
                                <br />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    articles: state.home.articles,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    onLoad: data => dispatch({ type: 'HOME_PAGE_LOADED', data}),
    onDelete: id => dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_ARTICLE', id}),
    setEdit: article => dispatch({ type: 'SET_EDIT', article }),
});

Mainview.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  };

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (withStyles(styles)(Mainview));
```

Soy nuevo en React, por lo que me surgen muchas dudas, pero tengo muchas ganas de seguir aprendiendo y aportar a la comunidad, les agradezco de antemano todo su apoyo!